# Why does my phone burn out USB cables when plugging them into my car?

Tags: usb, charging

I have an Oppo A73 phone, and over the last week it has started burning out USB cables (puff of smoke, cable no longer charges) when plugging it into my car (2015 Suburu Outback).

It had never done this previously, but I've lost 3 cables to it now. If the phone is plugged in before I turn on the car, it's fine, but if there's power in the cable when plugging it in... zap!

I'm assuming it's short circuiting against the phone's jack, but I don't know how to stop it happening. How do I stop it doing this? (And if you can suggest why it has suddenly started, that would be awesome too).

Comment: My wife's phone works just fine in the same car :(

Comment: Then it's best taken to a service center to fix. One can only guess *why* like you did

Comment: be prepared to lose your data

Comment: try keeping a lower voltage charging adapter and be careful, if the phone is creating smoke then there are chances that it may melt the steel charging pin